# Blazor component in a Razor pages web site - "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I know there are many questions here that refer to the same exception, but I haven't found any that cover my particular case.

I have an ASP.NET Core Razor pages web site, and this has been working fine for some time. I now added a Blazor server-side component to one page, and have started getting this exception when I hit that page. However, all usages of the context are `await`ed (absolutely everywhere, in the Blazor component and in all code in the Razor pages and dependent classes), and all appropriate code is async.

It looks like the problem is that Blazor holds on to the context, whereas Razor creates a new one for each request. I don't really claim to understand how this is causing the problem, nor what I can do to avoid it.

I'm not sure what code is worth showing, as I don't think it's the code per se that's the problem. In case it's of interest, here is the appropriate code in `Startup.cs`...

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
      services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
```

...and typical usage would be...

```cs
var basket = await _appDbContext.Basket
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.ID.ToString() == basketIdCookie);
```

Nothing very exciting there.

I tried using `AddDbContextFactory` when registering the context, but this gave a compiler error "`IServiceCollection` does not contain a definition for `AddDbContextFactory`". Don't know if it makes a difference, but this project uses .NET Core 3.1.

Can anyone explain how I'm supposed to handle the case of a context being used in a Blazor component within a Razor page?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to ensure thar for each request created new DbContext? Just put breakpoint in DbContext constructor.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I'm not creating contexts anywhere, it's all done by injection. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I’m trying to improve your debugging skills. And I’m proposing easy way how to validate your DI configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when integrating blazor in my existing MVC project. I solved it by following the dbcontextfactory pattern per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/). Basically you inject the DbContextFactory and create your own context with it. By doing this you ensure the context is created and disposed on every request. DbContextFactory is only available on .NET 5+ so if you have any previous .NET Core versions you would need to upgrade.

In the startup.cs register your dbcontext and dbcontextfactory but ensure you register your context lifetime as Transient and the options lifetime as Singleton:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>

        options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))), contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Transient, optionsLifetime: serviceLifetime.Singleton);



services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>

             options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
                                                 .UseLazyLoadingProxies());
```

Now that you have registered your services, instead of injecting your DBContext, you inject the DbContextFactory:

```
public class MyRepository
{ 
   private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _dbContextFactory;

   public MyRepository(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory)
   {
     _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
   }

   public async Task<Entities> GetAllEntities ()
   {
     using var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
     
     var entities = await context.MyEntities.ToListAsync();
     
     return entities;
   }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried registering the context as transient, but as that is the default, it didn't make any difference. Didn't try registering the lifetime as Singleton. What effect does that have?

Comment: Forgot to mention in my original post (which I'll update in a minute)that I tried using `AddDbContextFactory`, but it gave a compiler error. Don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm using .NET Core 3.1

Comment: Registering the lifetime as singleton is a configuration to be used with the DbContextFactory. As mentioned in the answer, DbContextFactory is only available in .NET 5+. I did the migration from .Net Core 3.1 to .Net 5 following this [ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio] with no major hassle in case you're interested.

Comment: My bad, didn't spot that you mentioned .NET 5+. I would like to upgrade, but am a bit nervous having had a serious issue upgrading another site from 2 to 3.1. Anyway, I guess if this is the way to fix the issue, I'll have to take the plunge. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in coming back to you. I just tried this in another project (.NET 5 already) where I hit the same problem, and it seems to work fine. Just one question though, do I need to call `CreateDbContext()` every time I want a context, or can I do this just once when the class that injects the factory is created? Thanks again.

Comment: Blazor components are considered long-lived which causes a dbcontext to live longer than necessary, for this reason they recommend to create a dbcontext per operation, this is using CreateDbContext() every time you make a call to the data base. This ensures there are no conflics if the component performs different operations concurrently.  Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looking at that link, it actually suggests doing what I mentioned, ie creating the context just once in `OnInitializedAsync` and then using that same context for the lifetime of the application.